# Does the last champion in a pack drop better loot?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it intentional that the last blue monster to die carries most of the loot?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68735/is-it-intentional-that-the-last-blue-monster-to-die-carries-most-of-the-loot)

I've noticed when fighting champion packs that the first two I kill usually drop less and worse loot than the last one. Is this "reward for killing the pack, rather than individuals" an actual game mechanic or just chance occurrence I keep running into?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its an actual game mechanic.

Usually, you have to kill all the elites to get your entire share of the loot. Its like the loot is divided into parts, with the last one having roughly 70% of the entire loot that they will drop.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the last mob in a pack drops bonus loot.  Each individual mob can drop items just like any other mob, however.  The "bonus" forces you to kill the whole pack versus trying to do a hit and run on a "leader" (that is sort-of the mechanic with uniques, though killing the minions beforehand makes the fight easier).

Comment: s/mob/monster. A mob is a pack of monsters.

Comment: @click https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mob_(video_gaming)